# ImageIO.read returns NULL, with no errors

Tags: java, image

The following code seems not to work, even though the file appears to be found just fine.

```
    images = new BufferedImage[32];
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        File file = new File("tiles\\"+i+".bmp");
        if (!file.exists()){
            System.out.println("File  "+i+" failed");
        }
        try { 
            fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.err.println(e + "" + i); 
        }
        try { 
            images[i] = ImageIO.read(fis); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            System.err.println(e + "" + i); 
        }
        if (images[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Image "+i+" failed");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: The result is me attempting to Graphics.drawImage(images[0]);, and it giving me a null pointer exception. This code here completes fine.

Edit: Changed moved the if(!file.exists()) as suggested, and wrapped the file in an input stream.

Comment: [RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Could you describe the result? A wild guess: the path in incorrect...

Comment: Why don'y you put your test if (!file.exists())    System.out.println("File  "+i+" failed");
 before the read?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ImageIO.read(file);** will return null if no registered **ImageReader** is found. Please check whether you have registered any **ImageReader**.

I think this code snippet could help you

```
File file = new File("bear.jpg"); // I have bear.jpg in my working directory  
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);  
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis); //reading the image file
```

You just need to wrap the file into an **FileInputStream** and then pass it to **read()**

Comment: I'm probably still not doing this properly, but what I did do was unsuccessful. I changed the code above to show what was changed.

Comment: Can you say what are your image file names in the disk?

Comment: @Naberius Can you say what are your image file names in the disk?  It is perfectly working in my case.

Comment: Sorry, no weekend internet access.
The files are named 0.bmp, 1.bmp, up to 31.
They're also stored in a folder called "tiles", but nothing changes by taking them out of said folder.

Comment: @Naberius Then try using File file = new File("tiles"+i+".bmp"); this.

Comment: Seems to be working now, for some reason. I guess it didn't like my naming, or the folder.
Also, the initial answer will be pretty helpful in the future.

Comment: This doesn't work in Java 8, the `BufferedImage` is null if I use it on an e.g. ".tif" image file that returns `true` for `file.exists()` (the `FileInputStream` isn't null).

Answer (score 50):

`ImageIO.read(*...)` will only load these image types **GIF**, **PNG**, **JPEG**, **BMP**, and **WBMP**.

Any other image type will return `null` without error.

*reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html*

*I do realize this is not a solution to the specific original problem but it is a solution to the question asked.*

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try wrap you InputStream into BufferedInputStream:

fis = new FileInputStream(file);  ==>
new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

Answer (score -1):

Use `new File(getClass().getResource("tiles\\"+i+".bmp"));`