# Java Convert PPM Byte array to JPG image

Tags: java, arrays, jpeg, bufferedimage, ppm

Currently working on Image manipulation in Java

I have the byte `array(PPM)` of size 921600 (640*480*3)

```
byte[] image; // PPM

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image));
```

image is null.

Tried with `ImageMagic` and `JAI` libraries. But it does not help me.

Is it possible to get the RGB components from byte array and convert it to JPG file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check for a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943962/imageio-read-returns-null-with-no-errors

Comment: If your `byte[] image` was actually a PPM file (or the bytes in PPM format), JAI ImageIO (`jai_imageio.jar`) would be able to read it. However, from your answer, it seems to be just the "raw" pixels (ie. the width, height and maxval should be stored *inside* the byte array in PPM format).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Code (which will convert PPM(byte array to Buffered image and you can save buffered image to the file)

// Method Call

```
BufferedImage image = ppm(width, height, 255, byte[]);
```

//Method Definition

```
static public BufferedImage ppm(int width, int height, int maxcolval, byte[] data){
        if(maxcolval<256){
            BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            int r,g,b,k=0,pixel;
            if(maxcolval==255){                                      // don't scale
                for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    for(int x=0;(x<width)&&((k+3)<data.length);x++){
                        r=data[k++] & 0xFF;
                        g=data[k++] & 0xFF;
                        b=data[k++] & 0xFF;
                        pixel=0xFF000000+(r<<16)+(g<<8)+b;
                        image.setRGB(x,y,pixel);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    for(int x=0;(x<width)&&((k+3)<data.length);x++){
                        r=data[k++] & 0xFF;r=((r*255)+(maxcolval>>1))/maxcolval;  // scale to 0..255 range
                        g=data[k++] & 0xFF;g=((g*255)+(maxcolval>>1))/maxcolval;
                        b=data[k++] & 0xFF;b=((b*255)+(maxcolval>>1))/maxcolval;
                        pixel=0xFF000000+(r<<16)+(g<<8)+b;
                        image.setRGB(x,y,pixel);
                    }
                }
            }
            return image;
        }
        else{


            BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            int r,g,b,k=0,pixel;
            for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
                for(int x=0;(x<width)&&((k+6)<data.length);x++){
                    r=(data[k++] & 0xFF)|((data[k++] & 0xFF)<<8);r=((r*255)+(maxcolval>>1))/maxcolval;  // scale to 0..255 range
                    g=(data[k++] & 0xFF)|((data[k++] & 0xFF)<<8);g=((g*255)+(maxcolval>>1))/maxcolval;
                    b=(data[k++] & 0xFF)|((data[k++] & 0xFF)<<8);b=((b*255)+(maxcolval>>1))/maxcolval;
                    pixel=0xFF000000+(r<<16)+(g<<8)+b;
                    image.setRGB(x,y,pixel);
                }
            }
            return image;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how could I write it in Kotlin/Android?

Comment: @AlanDonizete I believe you can use same function. However, I have little idea on Android.

Comment: I had to change some stuff but could make it work, thanks! (sadly, I don't have access to the code anymore, so I can't post it here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WritableRaster` to set the pixels in the image for you:

---

For a grayscale image, you will have a byte array like this:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[width * height];
```

To make an image, use:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, arr);
```

---

For a color image, you will have an array like this:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[width * height * 3];
```

So, to make an image, use:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, arr);
```

---

You may need to mess this the TYPE in the first line. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to choose which type your image is.