# byte[] to jpg image?

Tags: java, image, byte

I have the following code, that transforms an Image into a byte[]:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("Path/To/Custom/image.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

This code works totally fine, at least I get a byte array containing different values. But now comes the difficult part: The byte[] has to be reconstructed into am image again. The following code does not work, `ImageIO.read(...)` returns null. I read the documentation, but still I can not find out what to change so that the code functions in the way I want it to.

```
ByteArrayInputStream ba = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ba);
//image is always null, no matter what the stream or the byte values are.
```

Comment: Can you try to put the ImageIO.read () in a try-catch-block and tell us if an error occurs and if so which one?

Comment: oh sorry for not being specific enough. I already tested in try catch, but there is no exception. ImageIO.read(...) just returns null, but the original image is not null. This code here is very short to simplify things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class ByteArrayToImage {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("sample.jpg"));
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos );
      byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
      ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
      BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read(bis);
      ImageIO.write(bImage2, "jpg", new File("output.jpg") );
      System.out.println("image created");
   }
}
```

Modify this to your needs.

Comment: Your code works, mine does not. But I do not see any difference?

Comment: If I am to be honest, I do not know what the difference is. I just typed out from memory what I usually do

Comment: Okay, this is also the way how I think it must work. I used you code (which is actually really the same than mine ^^) and tested it. It worked. After that I included the byte[] into a dynamic byte array and then re-read it. After that it did not work. Maybe the streams must reference the same byte[]?

Comment: What is this "dynamic byte array"? Can you include the code you use in your question @F_Schmidt

Comment: Well, it was my mistake. I had an error in a different part of my code. This code snippet works like a charm. Just a hint which might be helpful: I am using this to create a binary network protocol, but for that I use `ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", bos );` instead of jpg, because `png` is a wide spread format. Maybe it helps someone ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try reading an `ByteArrayInputStream` on `ImageIO.read()` not an `ByteArrayOutputstream`.

Comment: You got a good eye! but it was not the mistake, it was just a copy-paste-fail into stackoverflow ;)

Comment: What do you need the BufferedImage for?

Comment: I want to write images byte by byte and send them to a server. I know that I could just use a DataOutputStream, but I do not like that solution. I really want to create this image -> byte and bytes -> image transformation.

Comment: But are you sure that the file really exists and is found?

Comment: Read this, maybe it helps you:  (But I am not sure) https://stackoverflow.com/a/9944029/13189807